# Database to #c (username & password) -> error

Tags: c#, database, security, integrated

I'm working on a project of school but im getting an error:

"Keyword not supported: 'integrated security'"
Can someone help me with this?

Here is a picuture: http://gyazo.com/5a16cde702601e20c811339c01b1911c

Language: Dutch

Code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string database = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;Integra‌​ted Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;InitialCatalog=loonberekening";
            SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(database);
            SqlCommand Selectcommand = new SqlCommand("select * from loonberekening.tblInloggen where id = '" + this.txtGebruikersnaam.Text + "' and passwoord= '" + this.txtPaswoord.Text + "' ;", myConn);
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            myConn.Open();
            myReader = Selectcommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Gebruikersnaam en paswoord is correct");
                startmenu.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dit is een gedupliceerde paswoord en gebruikersnaam... Acces verboden");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and paswoord zijn niet correct, Probeer opnieuw");
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL server management studio

Comment: did you attach your database in `SQL Server Management Studio`?

Comment: try this connection string ` Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;
AttachDbFileName=C:\MyFolder\MyData.mdf;`

Comment: Just as a sidenote, you might want to look into `parameterised queries`, your query is suggestive to SQL Injections this way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order in your connection it should be Initial catalog first before the integrated security

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"DataSource=sadf;Initial Catalog=asdf;Integrated Security=TRUE");
```

Comment: it is saying "keyword not supporting: 'datasource'"

Comment: put space between DATA SOURCE

Comment: Now im getting this error: http://gyazo.com/5725c180382bf3a88755beaca3a83518  (picture)

Comment: what version of SQL server you're using?

Comment: i think your database isn't created yet in the DB, or if it is, your servername/instance name is incorrect.

Comment: my database is not created in database? but i attached it and what do you mean with servername/instance? and how can i see if my database is created?

Answer (score 0):

try this  if your database file is attached In `SSMS`

```
string database = @"Data Source=.; Integrated Security; 
                  Initial Catalog=loonberekening; Connect Timeout=30;"
```

If you want **LocalDB automatic instance with specific data file** then

```
string database = @"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true; 
                  AttachDbFileName=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;"
```

**Note:**
  Use  this `loonberekening.dbo.tblInloggen` instead of this `loonberekening.tblInloggen` in your `Select Statement`

Something like this

```
SqlCommand Selectcommand = 
new SqlCommand("select * from loonberekening.dbo.tblInloggen where id = '" +
 this.txtGebruikersnaam.Text + "' and passwoord= '" + this.txtPaswoord.Text + "' ;", myConn);
```

Comment: The second one is working but now im getting this: http://gyazo.com/e6e69199365fdd3674f85a780716ed44 and here is a picture of my database: http://gyazo.com/8e0f827c264e0b0d755d486190224131   dbo.tblInloggen doesnt work also

Comment: @termted try this `loonberekening.dbo.tblInloggen`

Comment: loonberekening.dbo.tblInloggen didnt work... :( what do you mean with see edit?

Comment: The string database = @"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true; 
                  AttachDbFileName=E:\gip_stap_2\loonberekening.mdf;" is working for me and the ("select * from loonberekening.dbo.tblInloggen where id  also but now im gettin this error: http://gyazo.com/a08f915d626a2a088dc93bdd03b6061e